# How to seperate list B based on list A

Tags: python-3.x

I have list A of four fixed points. List B contains the positions of moving point M. M's paths are A0 --> A1, then A1 --> A2, then A2 --> A3, then A3 --> A2, then A3 --> A2 and and finally A2 --> A3.

```
A = [[0, 0], [0, 5], [0, 10], [5, 10]]

B = [[0, 0], [0.01, 2], [0, 4.02], [0, 5.03],
     [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10.05],
     [1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 9.97],
     [4, 10], [3, 10], [2, 10], [1, 10], [0, 10.05],
     [0, 9], [0, 8], [0, 6], [0, 5], 
     [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10]]
```

I would like to separate list B into the paths and print out a number of moving paths:
Expected output:

```
There are 6 moving paths:
[[0, 0], [0.01, 2], [0, 4.02], [0, 5.03]]
[[0, 5.03], [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10.05]]
[[0, 10.05], [1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 9.97]]
[[5, 9.97], [4, 10], [3, 10], [2, 10], [1, 10], [0, 10.05]]
[[0, 10.05], [0, 9], [0, 8], [0, 6], [0, 5]]
[[0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10]]
```

The following code prints out only 3 paths. Can anyone help me out?

```
# Initialize a list to store the paths
paths = []

# Loop through the fixed points in A
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    # Initialize a list to store the current path
    path = []
    # Loop through the points in B
    for j in range(len(B)):
        # Check if the current point is between the fixed points
        if A[i] <= B[j] <= A[i+1] or A[i+1] <= B[j] <= A[i]:
            # Add the current point to the current path
            path.append(B[j])
    # Add the current path to the list of paths
    paths.append(path)

# Print the number of moving paths and the paths themselves
print("There are", len(paths), "moving paths:")
for path in paths:
    print(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve that but it's showing the start point and end point as a path. if u don't need it remove that paths

```
def is_close(point1, point2, threshold=0.1):
    return abs(point1[0] - point2[0]) <= threshold and abs(point1[1] - point2[1]) <= threshold

A = [[0, 0], [0, 5], [0, 10], [5, 10]]
B = [[0, 0], [0.01, 2], [0, 4.02], [0, 5.03],
     [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10.05],
     [1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 9.97],
     [4, 10], [3, 10], [2, 10], [1, 10], [0, 10.05],
     [0, 9], [0, 8], [0, 6], [0, 5], 
     [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10]]

paths = []
current_path = []

for point in B:
    current_path.append(point)
    for fixed_point in A:
        if is_close(point, fixed_point):
            paths.append(current_path)
            current_path = [point]

paths.append(current_path)

print(f"There are {len(paths)} moving paths:")
for path in paths:
    print(path)
```

Output -

```
There are 8 moving paths:
[[0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0.01, 2], [0, 4.02], [0, 5.03]]
[[0, 5.03], [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10.05]]
[[0, 10.05], [1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 9.97]]
[[5, 9.97], [4, 10], [3, 10], [2, 10], [1, 10], [0, 10.05]]
[[0, 10.05], [0, 9], [0, 8], [0, 6], [0, 5]]
[[0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10]]
[[0, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following what Bimesh Perera said, just add a slice to `path`

```
def is_close(point1, point2, threshold=0.1):
    return abs(point1[0] - point2[0]) <= threshold and abs(point1[1] - point2[1]) <= threshold

A = [[0, 0], [0, 5], [0, 10], [5, 10]]
B = [[0, 0], [0.01, 2], [0, 4.02], [0, 5.03],
     [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10.05],
     [1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [5, 9.97],
     [4, 10], [3, 10], [2, 10], [1, 10], [0, 10.05],
     [0, 9], [0, 8], [0, 6], [0, 5], 
     [0, 6], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10]]

paths = []
current_path = []

for point in B:
    current_path.append(point)
    for fixed_point in A:
        if is_close(point, fixed_point):
            paths.append(current_path)
            current_path = [point]

paths.append(current_path)

print(f"There are {len(paths)} moving paths:")
for path in paths[1: -1]:
    print(path)
```